# Apache Tomcat mapping

Tags: apache, tomcat, http-status-code-403

I have a problem with my server. I have Apache and Tomcat. I need all requests mount to Tomcat but /apache/*.

If I have this in my conf file:

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

JkWorkersFile /etc/httpd/conf/jk-workers.properties
JkLogFile     /var/log/httpd/mod_jk_log
JkLogLevel    info
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
JkMount /apache/* inprocess

JkMount       /* worker1
```

all works fine.

But now I need map `myserver:80/apache/*` to apache. So I tried this.NameVirtualHost *:80

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName IP_ADDRESS
            DocumentRoot /opt/apache-tomcat-5.5.20/htdocs/
            ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
            CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log combined
            SetEnvIf Request_URI "/apache/*" no-jk

</VirtualHost>
```

But it doesn't work. From now all addresses seem to be mapped to Apache. And I see in Chrome that I got a 403 Forbidden status code. I'm trying to fix this for 2 days but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
JkUnmount /apache/*
```